# Javascript won't redirect page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web-applications

FYI: I don't really know how to use StackOverflow so some command such as on click or others, I change it to capital so Stack won't throw error to me trying to post this.

Here is my code that trying to redirect page to another page after form submission. But it won't work for me. It seems like all the code has done all function except that it won't redirect to another page after PIN has enter correctly.

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link ="stylesheet" href="/static/stylesheets/index.css?v=1.0.0">
    <title>MAID - Homepage</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="message">
        <h1>Welcome to MAID</h1>
        <h3>Please enter your PIN</h3>

        <form name="pinForm" class="pinSubmit" onSubmit="return toLobby()" method="POST">
            <label for="pin">PIN</label><br>
            <input type="password" id="pinText" name="pinInput" onKeypress="return inputChange()">
            <input id="enter" type="submit" value="Enter!">
        </form> <br>
        <div class="createRoomClass">
            <button id="createRoom" onClick="randomPin()">Create Room</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS Code

```
var pinHolder = [];

function randomPin() {
    var random = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000);
    pinHolder.push(parseInt(random));

    window.alert(random);

    console.log(pinHolder);
    console.log(typeof(random));
    console.log(pinHolder[pinHolder.length - 1]);
}

function toLobby() {
    // var formPIN = document.forms["pinForm"]["pinInput"].value;

    // console.log(formPIN);

    // if (formPIN == pinHolder[-1]) {
    //     window.location.replace("http://127.0.0.1:5000/lobby");
    // } else if (formPIN == "") {
    //     alert("No PIN has enter");
    // } else if (formPIN != pinHolder[-1]) {
    //     alert("Wrong PIN");
    // }

    var enterPIN = parseInt(document.getElementById("pinText").value);

    if (enterPIN == pinHolder[pinHolder.length - 1]) {
        alert("Successfully enter");
        window.location.href = "lobby.html";
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("Wrong PIN or no PIN has enter")
        return false;
    }
    console.log(enterPIN);
}

function inputChange() {
    var content = document.getElementById("pinText").value;
    return content.length < 6;
}
```

I also try this

```
window.location.href = "";
window.location.replace();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
self.location = "http://..."
```

http://net-informations.com/js/iq/load.htm